# CSS :root variables and SASS Functions

Tags: css, sass

in the Header of my HTML-Page i set the following CSS Variables:

```
:root{ 
  --data-color-primary: #ffcc00; 
  --data-color-secondary: #4b4b4b; 
}
```

In my SASS-File i use it as follow:

```
DIV.color {

   &.color-primary {
     background-color: var(--data-color-primary);
   }
   &.color-secondary {
     background-color: var(--data-color-secondary);
   }
}
```

Now i try to set the font-color depending on the brightness of the background-color:

```
@function set-notification-text-color($color) {
  @if (lightness($color) > 60) {
     @return #000000;
  } @else {
     @return #ffffff;
  }
}

DIV.color{
   &.color-primary {
      background-color: var(--data-color-primary);
      color: set-notification-text-color(var(--data-color-primary));
   }
}
```

But in my SASS-compliler i get the following i get the following Error:

> Error: argument `$color` of `lightness($color)` must be a color

How is ist possible to hand over der CSS variable to the function.

---

My Problem is, the CSS Variables are set in the Backend of my CMS by User (Liferay 7) an will be rendered in a *.FTL-File and is printed in the HTML-Code.

```
$primary: ${clr_primary};
$secondary: ${clr_primary};
```

and then i cant use the SASS-Variable $primary in my SASS-File.

Answer (score 44):

Use SASS variables in your CSS variables.

```
$primary: #ffcc00;
$secondary: #4b4b4b;

:root{ 
  --data-color-primary: #{$primary};
  --data-color-secondary: #{$secondary};
}
```

Now call your mixin

```
DIV.color{
   &.color-primary {
      background-color: $primary;
      color: set-notification-text-color($primary);
   }
}
```

---

Another options would be to create a mixin which retrieves the CSS variable

```
@function color($color-name) {
  @return var(--data-color-#{$color-name});
}
```

Now call that function like so

```
DIV.color {
   &.color-primary {
      background-color: color(primary);
      color: set-notification-text-color(color(primary));
   }
}
```

Check out this link for usefull information about combining CSS and SASS variables

https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/post/css4-variables-and-sass

Comment: @RaduM What specifically doens't work as of SASS 3.5.6?

Comment: If you use Sass variables inside a :root { } they will not be compiled to their values. Put the following code into https://www.sassmeister.com/ and you will see. Switch versions then.
$primary: #ffcc00;
$secondary: #4b4b4b;

:root{ 
  --data-color-primary: $primary;
  --data-color-secondary: $secondary;
}

Comment: @RaduM I see, thanks for pointing out. I updated the code and added a solution for SASS v3.5.6+ aswell.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to change CSS variables outside of :root you can do the following

```
.class {
  // sass-lint:disable no-duplicate-properties
  #{--background}: transparent;      
  #{--background-focused}: transparent;
  // sass-lint:enable no-duplicate-properties
}
```

and this compiles to

```
.class {
  --background: transparent;      
  --background-focused: transparent;
}
```