# How can I globally access a SCSS variable from a import into Angular styles.scss

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a shared library that contains many SCSS variables, for example colors such as `$gray-300: hsl(0, 0%, 91%)`. This shared library is imported into `styles.scss` eg

```
@import "~node_modules/@my-company/shared-ui/styles/styles";
```

I could get to the variable by also importing this into the component style sheet, but when I built I got the "budget exceeded" error. I am glad I got this warning as I did not realize it would duplicate everything in the shared styles.

Next, in `styles.scss` I thought I could just reshared/expose this in `:root` this, so I tried the following...

```
:root{
  --myapp-background-color: $gray-300  
}
```

However the `$gray-300` was not resolved.

My question is why the above did not work, and/or is there a way to do the above without changing the actual imported library?

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603815/css-root-variables-and-sass-functions. Also you can escape the scss var when you use it in CSS: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars

Comment: Great thankyou! Yes `:root{
  --myapp-background-color: #{$gray-300}  
}` does exactly what I am after