# Why do I need to escape a color SCSS variable with #{...}?

Tags: sass

I am using SCSS to style a web page. Now, I ran into a problem, which breaks down to mainly

```scss
$color-test: #123456;

.case-1 {
  color: $color-test;
}

:root {
  --css-color: $color-test;
}

.case-2 {
  color: var(--css-color);
}
```

Both entries for `color-1` and `color-2` do have the correct entries set in the generated CSS file. However, the `:root` in the CSS output still contains the unprocessed text `$color-test` and thus the case 2 is not colored in red.

I found on the net the [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603882) to escape the color in `#{...}`. So, the correct way to handle this is

```scss
:root {
  --css-color: #{$color-test};
}
```

I was a bit surprised that this worked and was necessary. I suspected the variable `$color-test` would be assigned the value `#123456`. Why do I need to set it this way? Where is it documented (so that I can avoid this bug in the future)?

Comment: [Sass Lang - Custom properties](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/declarations/#custom-properties), all there is to know about it, it's not a bug.

Comment: I never claimed this is a bug of scss but a bug of my (S)CSS code. I go an unexpected result and I am to blame here. I just wanted to understand the systematical structure. Could you make an answer out of your comment, so I can accept it?